# What would the atmospheric conditions of Venus sound like on its surface?

Tags: venus

Following on from the question [How long will it be light on Venus at night?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/how-long-will-it-be-light-on-venus-at-night), which is essentially about the visual properties of the Venusian atmosphere, this question is concerned about the sound-related properties.

Given that the properties of sound 'change' when it passes through different materials, densities and temperatures, **what would the atmospheric conditions of Venus sound on its surface?**

*Bonus question* what would an opera on Venus sound like?

Comment: Did you mean if the effects of wind were ignored? Everything would sound quite chaotic with the 250 mph wind!!

Answer (score 4):

Using [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound), I get a speed of sound of about 400 m/s for Venus' surface, so a bit higher than on Earth. But that doesn't change how it sounds by much, just your sense of acoustics (being able to gauge the size of a room by how long it takes for reflections to arrive).
Ignoring the whole 'being able to breathe' issue, the higher density (~150 times more dense than air) dampens the vocal cords more, so your opera would sound a few octaves lower.
[video: demonstration using helium and sulphur hexafluoride](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvvzItzLSxw).